# Why does `if Exception` work in Python

Tags: python, exception, boolean

In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27680814/3456281, the following construct is presented

```
a=[1,2]
while True:
    if IndexError:
        print ("Stopped.")
        break
    print(a[2])
```

which actually prints "Stopped." and breaks (tested with Python 3.4.1).

Why?! Why is `if IndexError` even legal? Why does `a[2]` not raise an `IndexError` with no `try ... except` around?

Comment: Well it was my answer and I didnt realize that its always _True._

Comment: This is truly interesting, I've never known about this

Comment: I deleted the answer, Im getting downvotes because of it :-)

Comment: @qqvc Wait... You were suggesting answers involving concepts that you didn't understand? Please don't do that.

Comment: I didnt understand what? I understand that question clearly.

Comment: Well, you said you didn't realize `IndexError` evaluates to True, so there is a lack of understanding there.  Also, it looks like this was an attempt to demonstrate a `try: except:` clause, but there is a lack of understanding of how Python's exception mechanism works since `if IndexError` isn't really useful.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All objects have a boolean value. If not otherwise defined, that boolean value is True.

So this code is simply the equivalent of doing `if True`; so execution reaches the `break` statement immediately and the `print` is never reached.

Comment: source for "if not otherwise defined, all objects are True"?

Comment: @Jasper: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__ says "If a class defines neither `__len__()` nor `__nonzero__()`, all its instances are considered true."

Comment: @Jasper: and in [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing): *Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while` condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false: [...] All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.* Exceptions are just more objects here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters correct and I'd add that it's common practice to test the existence of an object by `if object:`, which means that it's normal behaviour for objects to returns `True`

Comment: @MartijnPieters hum I just realised it's exactly what you said but in a more common-ground way.

Answer (score 3):

View the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), section Truth Value Testing under Built-in Types of The Python Standard Library. The first sentence, and the first sentence after the last bullet point answers your question.

> Any object can be tested for truth value ...

and

> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are
>   always true.

Here's the full text of the documentation, (content in brackets, `[]`, are added as an augmentation):

> 5.1. Truth Value Testing
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following
>   values are considered false:
>
> - `None`
> - `False`
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__bool__()` [`__nonzero__()` in Python 2] or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value `False`. [See Data Model, Special Method Names, section [Basic Customization](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customization), of The Python Language Reference]
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are
>   always true.
>
> Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always
>   return `0` or `False` for false and `1` or `True` for true, unless otherwise
>   stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations `or` and `and` always
>   return one of their operands.)

**Conclusion**

So since `Exception` does not have a `__bool__`, `__nonzero__`, or `__len__`, (nor fall under the other conditions listed above) an `Exception` object will always test as `True` in a boolean context.